# R: How to extract the string before first dot in R

Tags: r

I have a data set wherein a column looks like this:

```
29.027
103.851959 
-101.831299
39.9042.
36. 42.36.00.
```

I have tried:

```
dataset <- c('29.027', '103.851959', '-101.831299', '39.9042.', '36. 42.36.00.')
new <- sub("(^[^-]+)\\..*", "\\1", dataset)
```

the output is

```
29
103
-101
39.9042
36. 42.36.00
```

I want to get the number before the first dot (ie round it up to an integer), for example:

```
29
103
-101
39
36
```

Comment: your attempt was one character off, you want to set up a class that matches anything except `.` not `-`, so you need `sub("(^[^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", dataset)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this `sub` instead:

```
sub("\\..*", "", dataset)
```

Or you can try `strsplit`:

```
strsplit(dataset, "[.]")[[1]][1]
```